# Add a custom extra rotation to a quaternion

Tags: rotations, quaternions

I have a quaternion which represents a 3D object rotation, for example:

```
Quaternion(scalar:0.707107, vector:(0, 0, 0.707107))
```

I want to keep the current 3D object rotation, but add an extra rotation to it, for example:

```
Extra rotation to be added to quaternion: 
Rotate around point (34.5, -40, 0.0) in XY plane by 180°
```

I cannot figure out how to convert my extra rotation to a quaternion and add it to the previous quaternion. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation might help?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer provided on a mailing list:

---

Hi,

convert your rotation to a quaternion and multiply both quaternions to
get a quaternion representing both rotations. Note that quaternion
multiplication is not commutative.

See these links for some handy explanations and shortcuts
https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToQuaternion/index.htm
https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/index.htm

-Marian

#### Another answer on a mailing list:

---

Just for clarification: A quaternion does *not* describe a "rotation around point", but just a rotation in 3D.

If you want to rotate around a given point, you first have to apply a translation to the origin, then the rotation (which might be given as a quaternion) and then a translation back to the intended rotational centre.

Cheers, Rainer

Comment: The second answer gives the reason why the first answer does not apply to your question.